# TableLayoutPanel MouseClick programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, events, click, tablelayoutpanel

I wanted to create a TableLayoutPanel programmatically. I did it and it works and show all correctly. But now I want to add a Click or MouseClick event but it doesn't fire. This is my code:

```
private void CreateTable()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();

    if (table == null)
        GenerateTable();
    else
        table.Controls.Clear();

    ResizeTable();

    CreateRowStyles();
    CreateColumnStyles();

    GenerateColumnHeaders();

    GenerateRows();

    Controls.Add(table);

    this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Table generate:

```
private void GenerateTable()
{
    table = new TableLayoutPanel()
    {
        RowCount = 1 + rowCount,
        ColumnCount = 1 + columnCount,
        Location = new Point(0, 0),
        BackColor = Color.White,
        Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height),
        GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.FixedSize
    };
    table.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(table_MouseClick);
}
```

table_MouseClick:

```
void table_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("h");
}
```

Is there anything wrong? I missed anything? 0 events working with the table.

Comment: I said that it works and shows all correctly, yes i added it to the window.

Comment: No, 0 events working.

Comment: BringToFront does nothing. Still not working. The cells are a mix of buttons (headers) and a ControlUser with some pictureBox.

Comment: Have you tried it without content? Maybe you are clicking on a `PictureBox` rather than the table...

Comment: The TableLayoutPanel doesn't fire and event if you click its content? so i have to add a MouseClick handler to all of the childs???

Comment: Yes, you have to. But you might consider making your own control (inheriting from `TableLayoutPanel`) where you can add this funtionality programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 table.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(table_MouseClick);
```